# Autocomplete text for more than one countries in google map api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to pick the cities for Singapore country in android editbox. So i use the **place Autocomplete text** by using this url,
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&type=(cities)&components=countries:sg&input=k.
I get the cities in singapore. But my question is, I want to get two country's cities (like Singapore and Malayasia) by using the same url.

I already tried to change the parameters like, **&&components=countries:sg,my**. But I get the response as **INVALID_REQUEST**.
Please friends, Kindly help me to solve this.I am in running short of time.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you don;t mind hitting google api service two times simply hit the service twice times by givng both countries name and store it in static data type and then display

Comment: that means, I need to hit one api with Singapore and other api with Malaysia - in a single click. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, on the response of one service you can call another and store the previous response in static data type. It might take some time but it will give the result u desire.

Comment: It would be better if you call the web service 2wice

Comment: did you get it solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&type=(cities)**&components=country:es|country:uk|country:us**